# gpg --gen-key not working on "su -l", but working on local terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, encryption, gnupg

When I try to use "gpg --gen-key" (v2.1.2 on archlinux) with an user I just created ("backtest"), it works when I open a terminal for that, but not when I'm logged in with another user and then "su -l backtest".

That's what I'm running:

```
[backtest@server ~]$ echo "pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses" >.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf 
[backtest@server ~]$ echo RELOADAGENT | gpg-connect-agent
OK
[backtest@server ~]$ GPG_TTY=`tty` gpg --gen-keygpg
```

and that's what I get:

```
We need to generate a lot of random bytes. It is a good idea to perform
some other action (type on the keyboard, move the mouse, utilize the
disks) during the prime generation; this gives the random number
generator a better chance to gain enough entropy.
gpg: agent_genkey failed: Operation cancelled
Key generation failed: Operation cancelled
```

Comment: maybe this is relevant, but the pinentry is done in a kind of a dialog, like this image: http://www.soum.co.jp/misc/_images/gpg-agent.png

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess that if it wants to measure mouse movements to generate the random numbers for the key, it needs to talk to the window manager in some special way.  `su` changes the UID of your _shell_, but your window manager is still running under your UID — and therefore, `gpg` might not have the necessary privileges to talk directly to the window manager.

Comment: hm, that makes some sense. But can it detect mouse movements on a "real" local terminal?